# Using the -tim suffix

Tags: academic-latin, derivation, suffixes

I am looking for some guidelines for using the *-tim* suffix in the sense "one by one".
Some examples:
[*guttatim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dguttatim),
[*nominatim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnominatim),
[*paul(l)atim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpaulatim),
[*syllabatim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsyllabatim),
[*viritim*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dviritim).
(It seems that [this is not the only use of the suffix](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=tim&lang=la), but I want to focus on this particular use.)
Can I use this suffix productively?
If yes, are there rules for attaching it to a word?

This is related to a specific problem that I have: I want to say "one faculty at a time".
My university uses the word *facultas* for "faculty" — translating, for example, "the faculty of humanities" with *facultas rerum humanarum*.
Would *facultatim* be correct?

An example sentence:
"New doctors are promoted faculty by faculty."
My translation:
*Doctores novi facultatim creantur.*

Comment: Good question. Does *interim* contain the same suffix?

Comment: If you want to sidestep the problem *facultates seriatim* conveys one-by-one. Or, a word for randomly occurs in the Evangelium board-game; I think it's *sparsim.*

Comment: @Cerberus, I'm not sure. Not all words ending in *-im* have a similar meaning, so I suspect there are at least two suffices. I guess that *interim* has a (semantically) different suffix (*-im*?), but it's just a guess.

Comment: @Hugh, *sparsim* means "scatteredly" or "here and there", so it doesn't really fit the sequential nature. But *facultates seriatim* is a good idea! I added an example sentence in my question so that any suggested phrase can be adapted to a full sentence. I don't know how to use *seriatim* in that sentence, but there must be a way...

Comment: Seems like *facultatim* would be using the suffix *-im*, not *-tim*, since the stem of the noun is *facultat-*.

Comment: A possible workaround would be something like *singuli e facultatibus*.

Comment: @TKR, true, but *facultatatim* sounds bad. Perhaps one could argue *facultattim > facultatim*. I am admittedly puzzled about this suffix, and that's why I ask. Perhaps *e singulis facultatibus* would emphasize that it's one faculty at a time, not just one doctor at a time (which is more obvious in the context).

Comment: I'd be a little suspicious of a form like *facultatim* because there don't seem to be any attested words with *-tim* or *-im* formed from a noun in *-tat-* (http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=tatim&lang=la). *E singulis facultatibus* works well, I think.

Comment: @TKR, the lack of sufficient precedent is actually what drove me to ask this question. My attempt is indeed suspicious, but it is the best one-word translation I know and will probably be understood correctly. *E singulis facultatibus* is certainly a much safer choice.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary lists only the suffix *-im*, not *\*-tim*. It says *interim, partim, ceterim, paulatim* contain this suffix *-im*, which probably originates in an old accusative form of a nominative ending *-is*. It seems the *-t-* before it is a separate suffix, possibly related to the *-t-* in supine stems.

Comment: @Cerberus, interesting! Perhaps that makes *facultatim* a bit more credible, given that the stem is *facultat-*. Do you want to give that dictionary entry as a (partial) answer?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: I'm not sure: it seems relevant, but doesn't answer your question directly (it doesn't say anything about productivity or about *facultatim*). I do think *facultatim* is all right, though.

Comment: @Cerberus, I'm not sure I can get a full direct answer at all; there might be too little evidence to judge productivity. Therefore details about the suffix *-im/-tim* would make a welcome partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Facultatim* would be a good translation of "one faculty at a time," but only if you're talking about human ability (first sight, then reason, then hearing, then perception, and so on). If you're talking about university faculty then I'm not sure what the right word is.

Comment: The choice of *facultas* as "faculty" is already given to me, so the question is really whether *facultatim* is a correct form. Thanks for the confirmation! The general question about *-tim* remains open, but help with my special case is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All the adverbs in this answer (all four groups), suggests Ainsworth (1780), are colloquial accusatives. Compare--

> aetatem =for a long period of time, for ages.
>   prorsum =straight on
>   prorsum et rursum =back and forth
>   passim =everywhere
>   interim = in
>   between
>   sparsim =scattered
>   praesertim =foremost.

In a sub-group of these the stem ending, *-t-,* indicates a verbal adjective.

> seriatim=one by one
>   partim = piece by piece
>   guttatim =drop by drop
>   particulatim =a littlebit at a time

The 2 following groups make use of this *-tim* suffix to indicate analogous incremental units.
(grammar)

> literatim, letter by letter
>   verbatim,  word by word
>   phrasatim
>   (Quintilian)

(military)

> viritim =man by man
>   manipulatim =platoon by platoon
>   centuriatim
>   =company by company

IMO .1. the absence of any parallel adverbs for 'class by class,' 'tutorial group by tutorial group,' and 'university by university' makes *facultatim* an anomaly.

.2. The *-t-* in *facultatim* is part of the noun stem, and to create a verbal or pseudo-verbal stem to match the other examples would create *facultatatim.* (vid. sup. *guttatim* )

.3. There is a certain objectification in any form of administration but especially in the army which describes men as units.

However I may be being too timid, or too set in my ways.

Tentatively, I am out of practice and was never fluent, may I suggest:

> Quos dignos clarosque illos doctores quanquam facultatem seriatim
>   eligere decet.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point of departure for all of these is partim, originally the acc. sing. of pars (classical part-em), but later lexicalised as an adverb. From this, speakers isolated the pseudo-suffix -tim and attached it to the stem of other words, like gutta-tim. At a third stage this was reanalysed as gutt-atim and the new pseudo-suffix -atim was used to form words like nomin-atim. I assume (and this is actually what you are asking) that they were relatively productive.